# Sort/Order List of points based on another list of points (LineString) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, turfjs

Lets say that i have a LineString (A car route):

```
let lineCoords = [
[ 10.964832305908203, 41.004681939880314 ],
[ 10.977363586425781, 40.99096148527727 ],
[ 10.983200073242188, 40.97075154073346 ],
[ 11.02834701538086, 40.98372150040732 ],
[ 11.02508544921875, 41.00716631272605 ],
];
```

And a another LineString (The stops that i have to make)

```
let arrayOfPoints = [
[ 10.964832305908203, 41.004681939880314 ],
[ 10.994186401367188, 41.01947819666632 ],
[ 10.977363586425781, 40.99096148527727 ],
[ 10.983200073242188, 40.97075154073346 ],
[ 11.02508544921875, 41.00716631272605 ],
[ 10.964832305908203, 41.004681939880314 ],
[ 11.02834701538086, 40.98372150040732 ],
];
```

Now i wanna sort arrayOfPoints based on lineCoords

How can i make it?

Can [Turf](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/) help?

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about what you mean when you say "sort based on"? What feature of `arrayOfPoints` will tell you the sort order of `lineCoords`

Comment: Sure. imagine that a car go in a route, lineCords are in order, they form a polyline (the route) so the first point is the start, then i have multiples stops (arrayOfPoints) without an order, so i need to know which stops im going to hit in order

Comment: I see…one problematic thing in this case is that your start and end point are the same. So when you encounter that in the `arrayOfPoints` does it sort first or last?

Comment: That coordinates are just an example, that's a tricky example (can happen) but for this question lets make them different